# Need help making a calculator using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

This is part of my assessment and we have to use JavaScript HTML and PHP to make a calculator with buttons, **not fields**.

I have managed to make the 'interface' but cannot workout how to make the buttons work. I need the numbers to show in the input field (has to be readonly)

What I'm asking for is help with making the buttons I've created show in the input field:

> I need to show the input within the text field

**HTML**

```
</head>
<body>
    <input id="ip1" type="text" readonly="readonly"/><br/>
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
    <button>CE</button> </br>
    <button>4</button>
    <button>5</button>
    <button>6</button>
    <button>/</button> <br>
    <button>7</button>
    <button>8</button>
    <button>9</button>
    <button>*</button> </br>
    <button>0</button>
    <button>-</button>
    <button>+</button>
    <button>=</button> </br>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript** (jQuery)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function()  {
            $.post("calc.php",  { formText : $("#ip1").val()  },
                function(data, status) {  $("#ip1").val(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $_POST['formText'];
?>
```

Comment: Looks like homework. Not sure what the actual question is.

Comment: @Evilzebra I've edited it now hopefully its clearer

Comment: Do you really have to send every single button click to the server? Can't you just write the expression to the readonly input box and send it to php when they click `=`? Also, readonly only means that it can't be typed into by the client. Anything can be done in script still just as if it wasn't readonly.

Comment: If you still want to do the button solution just grab the innerHTML. Or using jQuery you could do something like `$('#ip1').val( $('#ip1').val() + this.innerHTML )` put that inside the onclick handler.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn thank you, I get what you mean by that but I'm new to this could you help me achieve this

Comment: @Evilzebra what do you mean, "looks like homework"? It's obviously homework, even says so in the post.

Comment: @minseong I initially thought it was one of those "here is my homework, can you do it for me" questions. I was mistaken.

Comment: onclick of a button, get the text inside the button tag (Something like: `$(this).text()`). Then if that is equal to `=`, get the value from the input and send it to the server and populate input with response. Else (not `=`) append text to the input box to build the expression. Add a little error checking in there (If clicking symbol and last button was a symbol, change the last symbol instead of appending, things like that).

Answer (score 2):

You can get the clicked button text by `.text()` first then set it to input field by `.val(text)`. Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function()  {
        var val = $(this).text();
        if($.isNumeric(val)){ //for checking numeric number
            $("#ip1").val(val);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is a start. Only error would be that you probably want to append the number instead of overwriting it. To finish this you would still need to handle symbols and sending to the server.